# Sharing storage between instances of same web app

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I built a web application that i have running on multiple raspberry pis, I wanted to add storage that is shared by all the web app instances. Basically what I want to achieve is for each instance I open in my browser it saves the device name and URL to my browser (Local storage is what I went with but it's not shared) the web app would then open the storage read all previously accessed pis for easy switching.

I tried to do this using local storage but didn't work as apparently it's per instance and not shared. anyone can suggest a proper way to achieve this ?

Comment: Isn't that what servers are made for?

Comment: i don't see how a servers solves my issue. Perhaps you didn't get what i'm trying to achieve. i need things to be saved client side if there's such a thing

Comment: It's not "a web application", it's multiple applications - presumably on different domains as well. You need some way to have these instances to know about each other, but no the browser hardly will help with that. You need some kind of server-side central registry. (Decentral will work as well but is more complicated). You can use a browser session for communication (cross-domain XHR, cross-frame messaging etc) but that's unnecessarily complicated either.

Comment: "Client side" is exactly 1 client/machine. A "client" is not the website itself, but the device it's running on. If you want to share info between multiple clients, you need a server.

Comment: what i need is some form of storage that is shared (not sure if that exists that's why i'm asking) then each instace of my web app i open would add itself to that list and then show that list too so i get to switch between all my raspberry pis without having to type URLs. hope this is a bit more clear

Comment: It's clear from the get-go. This "storage that is shared" is what a server/database is.

Comment: i know what a database and a server is. i asked if there's a way to do what i want without using any DB or servers. just like i would do by saving everything to a file and reading from it if i was writing a desktop app.

Comment: But, how would another pi access that file in your example situation? You'd need to save it to a network drive. And then you're back at the "server" idea.

Comment: i do not need it to be shared with other people. assume we are in the same network; we have 4 pis running my app. pi1 pi2 pi3 pi4. On my PC i access pi1 and pi2 those two will save themselves to my browser somehow. You access pi4 only. you will only see pi4 in the recently visited list.

Comment: Ah, so you want some kind of storage inside your OWN browser, that is always accessible, from every domain?

Answer (score 1):

Local storage is exactly as it sounds - *local* to the browser (and machine). It's used to store data between multiple sessions with the same app/website on the same machine/browser. If you want to share some information between multiple instances of the app running on different machines or in multiple different browsers you need to store it on the server.

*How* to store it on the server is then a separate question alltogether (with a wide range of options, e.g. writing to a file or a database). In any case, the implementation will need to be separate from the client app.

Answer (score 0):

Local storage keys are shared on a single device ***if*** requests originate on the same domain.

Consider the following example of how keys could be shared:

You have the domain `http://example.com`

You have two apps hosted at `http://example.com/app1/index.html` and `http://example.com/app2/index.html`

You have a local storage key for `last visited` where the value is a date string

If you go to app1, it sets the key.

If you go to app2, it will be able to retrieve the key set in app1.

Are you having trouble with getting localstorage to be shared across instances in this manner?

If the apps are on different domains, or you're trying to share information between devices, you'll have to use a server to share the data.

Comment: It's important to note that this storage only exists on one device/client, and is not shared between devices/clients.

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans yes, I've made that clearer in my answer. Thanks

Comment: well that's exactly what i'm doing same key but it appears that each device creates its own list. and yes all my devices are on the same network. 

and again i do not want device**S**/client**S**. all i want is device**S** <-> Client.

Comment: @TheBrash as other posters are telling you, yes, that's the expected behavior. If you want to share information between devices, you'll need a server. My answer applies only to a single device on a single domain.

Answer (score 0):

Local storage is local to the current domain. There is no storage that can freely be shared between all web pages built into a browser.

If you have multiple web applications / application instances, they need to know about each other to communicate (via [cross-frame messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)) and exchange their URLs to have each store them locally and display them. There are a few approaches how to do that:

- have the user explicitly add other domains he knows about so that you can contact them
- have the servers announce their presence on the local network (or use a configuration file on each server) so that they know about each other before serving the web site
- have a central ("storage") website at a known domain that every application website will contact